# Redirecting output of linux module build

Tags: linux, module, makefile, kernel

I'd like to redirect the output of my module build to segregate the artifacts from the source.

My makefile looks like:

```
    obj-m += hello-1.o

all:
    make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-eabi- -C /work/TI-Android-ICS-4.0.3_AM37x_3.0.0/kernel M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-eabi- -C /work/TI-Android-ICS-4.0.3_AM37x_3.0.0/kernel M=$(PWD) clean
```

This works correctly, except that the module output happens to be in my source directory. I tried adding O={path to my output dirctory} in each line, but then it failed to build with something like...

> ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.
>          include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.
>          Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.
>
> WARNING: Symbol version dump
>   /work/development/linux/driver/blah/Module.symvers
>              is missing; modules will have no dependencies and modversions.

I assume this stems from the fact that there is some output file from the kernel build that's used in the module build, and changing the output directory with "O=" collides with that.

Is there a method for accomplishing this using the existing build infrastructure?

Comment: Your question is unclear, but I'm guessing that `.../kernel` is your source directory, and also where the makefile that builds `modules` resides. Without seeing that makefile we can't give you a specific answer. Getting it to put its products elsewhere could be trivial, or a real pain.

Comment: @Beta Sorry for the lack of clarity.

The kernel does indeed reside at /work/TI-Android.../kernel.

My module source resides at /work/mymodule, which is where I'm executing my makefile listed above.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation for [the module system](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=tree;h=25918f9811eae1d657db2bccdfcb077038d9454c;hb=25918f9811eae1d657db2bccdfcb077038d9454c), it doesn't look good. Perhaps you can copy `.config` into your build directory and do a `make oldconfig && make modules-prepare` with `O=` set.

---

Alternatively, what happens if you run `make` from another directory?

```
/somewhere/else$ make -C /path/to/kernel ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-eabi- M=/your/module/dir modules
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the output when I execute the make from the 'other' directory still puts the output in the module source directory.  
Also, when I try the make oldconfig and make prepare (modules-prepare doesn't seem to be a valid target), it complains about the kernel directory not being clean.

Comment: Have you tried saving your `.config`, cleaning the kernel directory and then doing the preparation with `O=` set? Not allowing out-of-source builds on a dirty tree is common to at least automake and kbuild.

Answer (score 0):

This Makefile will solve your query

```
 obj-m += hello-1.o

all:
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-eabi- -C /work/TI-Android-ICS-4.0.3_AM37x_3.0.0/kernel M=$(PWD) modules_install INSTALL_MOD_PATH=<output directory for modules>

clean:
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-eabi- -C /work/TI-Android-ICS-4.0.3_AM37x_3.0.0/kernel M=$(PWD) clean
```